# Show MKPolyline on top of MapView when type is SatelliteFlyover?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mkpolyline

I want to show a few `MKPolylines` on top of MapKit's mapView. The problem is when setting the map type to `.satelliteFlyover` my polylines will disappear. If I change to just using `.satellite` they're visible.

```
mapView.type = .satelliteFlyover
mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
```

Comment: interesting, does the polyline also disappear with .hybridFlyover?

Comment: @dinosaysrawr I just tried with .hybridFlyover as well and the problem persist :/ I've played around trying to. add the overlays at last index etc, but still no luck.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. It doesn't work with either .satelliteFlyover or .hybridFlyover. It works properly with any of the other mapTypes

Comment: How did you solved this issue

Comment: @Shekhu Still no solution for his I'm afraid.

Comment: It seems that the line shows "under" the night/day scene... no solution yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60251655/mkpolyline-broken-when-using-type-satelliteflyover

Answer (score 1):

had a similar problem, and I found that the MKMultiPolylineRenderer in iOS 13 is much better for handling polylines on a flyover MapType. You need to do prepare all of your polylines in an array so you have ALL polylines available:

```
var multiArray = [MKPolyline]()
// CREATE ALL OF YOUR POLYLINES AND APPEND THEM TO multiArray
view.addOverlay(MKMultiPolyline(multiArray))
```

Then you need to create a section of code to handle MKMultiPolylines in `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer`. I literally copied my MKPolyline section and just changed any reference from `MKPolyline` to `MKMultiPolyline`.

IDK what to do if you can't change your target to iOS 13. Both flyover map types exhibit a similar situation before iOS 13. I'm also [having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974286/ios-mapkit-bug-using-mkcircle-overlays-in-satelliteflyover-and-hybridflyover-map) with MKCircle that I just can't fix on the flyover map types.