# MKPolyline broken when using type satelliteFlyover?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkpolyline

I would like to draw some Geodesic Polyline(great circle line) between points on Earth using Satellite Flyover map type.

```
// in viewDidLoad()

mapView.mapType = .satelliteFlyover
let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: [route.airport1, route.airport2], count: 2)
self.mapView.addOverlay(geodesic)

// rendering method
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        guard let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline else {
            print("else??")
            return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        }
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer.init(polyline: polyline)
        renderer.lineWidth = 1
        renderer.strokeColor = .systemTeal
        return renderer
    }
```

I am able to create the GeodesicPolyline partially, but the lines are not complete.

If I'm in iOS system dark mode, the line shows under the "night area".
[image: dark mode]

While the line shows under the "day area" if dark mode is disabled.
[image: bright mode]

I also tried using

```
self.mapView.addOverlay(geodesic, level: .aboveLabels)
self.mapView.addOverlay(geodesic, level: .aboveRoads)
```

but no help as well.  Any map type other than SatelliteFlyover or HybridFlyover is working well. I found a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917088/show-mkpolyline-on-top-of-mapview-when-type-is-satelliteflyover) but no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I found that the MKMultiPolylineRenderer in iOS 13 is much better for handling polylines on a flyover MapType. You need to do prepare all of your polylines in an array so you have ALL polylines available:

```
var multiArray = [MKPolyline]()
// CREATE ALL OF YOUR POLYLINES AND APPEND THEM TO multiArray
view.addOverlay(MKMultiPolyline(multiArray))
```

Then you need to create a section of code to handle MKMultiPolylines in `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer`. I literally copied my MKPolyline section and just changed any reference from `MKPolyline` to `MKMultiPolyline`.

IDK what to do if you can't change your target to iOS 13. Both flyover map types exhibit a similar situation before iOS 13. I should note that I don't use dark mode in my app, so I'm not sure if you'll see the same results I did. But this code fixed all of my broken/missing polyline problems.